# Discord.js bot command handler - split is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjwwHG0AWsk) to make a command handler for my discord bot using discord.js.

I've copied the code, but I got this error:

> TypeError: message.content.slice(...).spilt is not a function

My code can be found here: https://hastebin.com/ivipewutes.js

Comment: Flagging as off-topic as this is the result of a typo:  `split` vs `spilt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `split` as `spilt`

misspelled:

```
var cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).spilt(" ");
```

correct:

```
var cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
```

Make sure to always take a look at the Error you are getting, as it can give you a lot of insight about the potential cause of the problem.

Comment: I have glasses, but it seems I can't see today! I've missed so many spelling errors! Thanks, though, I'll try it!

Comment: @Eddie'sTech no worries, we all overlook stuff sometimes

Comment: Rather than answer these questions, comment to explain the typo and flag for closure as a typo.